# Error while running a .sh script via QProcess

Tags: qt, shell, qt4, qprocess

I have written a QT GUI program where pressing a button will execute a .sh script. The contents of the script is-

```
echo -e 'attach database 'testdatabase.db' as 'aj';\n.separator ","\n.import ora_exported.csv qt_ora_exported' | sqlite3 testdatabase.db
```

basically the script will import a .csv to an sqlite database. And when the script file (script.sh) is run manually from linux terminal ($./script.sh) it successfully imports the .csv file into the database table.

But, when I call the script from my QT program

```
void MainWindow::on_importButton_clicked()
{    
    QProcess process;
    process.startDetached("/bin/sh",QStringList()<<"/home/aj/script.sh");
}
```

it compiles successfully but gives an error message in console when the button is pressed at runtime.

Error: near line 1: near "-": syntax error
Error: cannot open "ora_exported.csv"

what could be causing this ???

**EDITED**

I have changed my .sh script now to--

```
echo -e 'attach database 'testdatabase.db' as 'aj';\n.separator ","\n.import /home/aj/ora_exported.csv qt_ora_exported' | sqlite3 testdatabase.db
```

Thus providing the path to my ora_exported.csv. As a result the runtime error [Error: cannot open "ora_exported.csv"] has gone but the other message [Error: near line 1: near "-": syntax error] is still coming.

Same as was observed in previous case, using ./script.sh is successfully importing data to sqlite3 db table file but QProcess is unable to.

Comment: script is run from directory where this file `ora_exported.csv` is not present and/or `path` variable doesn't contain directory where this file is located. Just add [third argument: `workingDirectory`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached), with proper value.

Comment: i have noted your suggestion and included directory path to the .csv in the script file. Still the situation is same. 

Can you guide me as to what the workingDirectory will be in my context. I was not able to get it from the QT docs link.

Comment: @MarekR was talking about the directory in which `QProcess` is called. Just add that directory to the `startDetached()` call OR call `setWorkingDirectory()` on the `process` instance, before calling `startDetacjed()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It looks strange that you are using external script to update database!
2. why you don't pass "ora_exported.csv" file name as a script argument? This would help solve the problem.
3. I was talking (typing) about this solution:

```c++
void MainWindow::on_importButton_clicked()
{    
    QProcess::startDetached("/bin/sh",
                            QStringList()<<"/home/aj/script.sh",
                            "<location of: 'ora_exported.csv' file>");
}
```

Comment: for testing / learning purpose I am using external script. Once I make a little headway I will go for direct db to db communications. For the time being it seems that your suggestion to give the location of .csv as an argument in the QProcess actually solved my problem. Thanks a lot. One small line explanation to this is also highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`echo` is a built in command of a shell that may behave differently.

E.g. take this test script: `echotest.sh`

```
echo -e "123"
```

Now we can compare different results:

```
$ bash echotest.sh
123
$ zsh echotest.sh
123
$ dash echotest.sh
-e 123
```

You are probably on some Ubuntu-like OS, where `/bin/sh` redirects to `dash`. That would explain the error around "-". So if you are using `echo`, set you shell specificially or ensure that your script works on all common shells.

---

Additionally, you are messing up your quotations

```
echo -e 'attach database 'testdatabase.db' as 'aj';\n.separator ","\n.import /home/aj/ora_exported.csv qt_ora_exported'
```

results in (no quotations in the first line)

```
attach database testdatabase.db as aj;
.separator ","
.import /home/aj/ora_exported.csv qt_ora_exported
```

but you pobably want

```
echo -e "attach database 'testdatabase.db' as 'aj';\n.separator ','\n.import /home/aj/ora_exported.csv qt_ora_exported"
```

Comment: okay, so i used /bin/bash during QProcess and no errors came but it still did not fire the .sh file

also, i used  "attach database 'testdatabase.db' as 'aj';\n.separator ','\n.import /home/aj/ora_exported.csv qt_ora_exported" but still the .sh script is getting executed from terminal but not from my QT application

Comment: presently there are no runtime errors (after using /bin/bash)

Comment: Add logging to get more insights (updated middle part of my answer).

Comment: thanx for the tips, but there were no errors observed hence the files for logging were not created.

Comment: Try using append mode and different files for different output types. (See edited code)

Comment: in Qt4 (look on tags) `startDetached` is static so your approach is not good (voted down).

Comment: @MarekR Your are right, I removed the middle part from my answer. Since part 1 still fixed a huge part of the problem and part 2 fixed a potential problem, I'd appreciate if you'd reconsider your downvote.